# timeout during the post-login phase connecting to SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql-server, integrated-authentication

I am trying to connect from desktop to SQL Server 2012 (on a different server) and getting the following error:

> Connection Timeout Expired. The timeout period elapsed during the post-login phase. The connection could have timed out while waiting for server to complete the login process and respond; Or it could have timed out while attempting to create multiple active connections. The duration spent while attempting to connect to this server was - [Pre-Login] initialization=190; handshake=4; [Login] initialization=0; authentication=102; [Post-Login] complete=14002; (Microsoft SQL Server)

The client is SQL Server Management Studio 2012. Firewall on the server is turned off. I *can* telnet to port 1433. And connecting from Studio on the server itself works fine. Desktop and Server are on the same segment; using Windows authentication.

Both Windows Server 2008R2 and SQL Server are just built from scratch.

What puzzles me is that *post-login* phase. I have a feeling that I am looking in the wrong place (that is, network connectivity); but don't know what the right place would be...

Comment: Does anything show up in the event log that corresponds to this?

Comment: Well, your question got me thinking... While there was nothing when I was attempting to login, there *was* an error when the computer started up, saying that it can't connect to domain controller. Once I rebooted DC, and rebooted this server - the problem went away... Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adapted from my comment that found your answer:

Check the event log. You will probably see something in there that points to the problem.

Comment: Ok, but I got this message connecting to SQL Azure, so I cannot check the eventlog

Comment: Just to point out for the record, SQL Azure is NOT the same as "SQL Server 2012 (on a different server)"